# Sense of oop python

Tags: python, oop

Hey I m started a proyect to learn more about OOP, about family relationship like: 'my father is carlos'
So I make a simple input as my_name: father_name:
I creeate a class to define the user who is completing the forms and another class to make the relationships (Also I want to save it in database but I dont wish this post be long so I skip it)

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self,name,fullname):
        self.name = name
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.parents = []
        self.show()

    def set_padres(self,madre,padre):
        self.padres.append(padre)
        self.padres.append(madre)

    def show(self):
        print(f"{self.name} {self.fullname} has been registred")
    

class Relationship:
    def __init__(self,nombre,apellido):
        self.p2p = {}
        self.name = name
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.id = self.name+"_"+self.fullname
        self.making_person()        

    def making_person(self):
        self.p2p[self.id] = Person(self.name,self.fullname)

    def making_user(self,father,mother):
        if not (padre and madre) in self.p2p[self.id].padres:
            self.p2p[self.id].set_padres(padre,madre)
    #then instantiate and save in database the name and father and mother s name
```

I really like it

But then I think: "Hey why I m doing this, what sense does it make" because if a do somenthing like that:

```
def person(name,father,mother):
    relationship = {}
    relationship[name] = [father,mother]
    print(relationship)
    #and then save in database the name and father and mother s name
```

(Obviously are some change in the different cases but the important is what I want to transmit, the concept)

And that is, more easy
So here is the question, ¿Why I should use oop in this case or any case if then when I want to save it in database I save the name and my father name ...? ¿I m using wrong oop or maybe I dont understand the concept?

I m new in this so be nice with me :)

Comment: In such a simple example it isn't necessary but things can become more complicated easily e. g. when handling legal, step and biological parents and e. g. calculate siblings of the different kinds from the data.

Comment: It's hard to make simple examples that really motivate OOP. But examples that really need OOP will be hard for beginners to understand.

Comment: Ah, okey I see thanks